# Application won't read username on IIS

Tags: c#

I have this application where I login by the PC user. I'm using this:

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        CurrentUser = Factory.Users.List(item => item.Username.ToLower() == cToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return CurrentUser != null;
}
```

> Note: .List(), is a method I created to list all database Users (in
>   this case).

Everything works fine. But when I publish my Website on my IIS, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is returning nothing, no user at all. What is wrong with it? Any suggestion?

Comment: have you read this? does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056487/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-always-string-empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable IIS `Windows Authentication` and ***Deny*** `Annomyous acces`. You can either configure your IIS or update your configuration file as follows,

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```